# typeof().GetTypeInfo().Assembly vs typeof().Assembly

Tags: c#

I've seen examples of both the following code:

```cs
typeof(Type).GetTypeInfo().Assembly
```

And...

```cs
typeof(Type).Assembly
```

I can't see the difference when I've experimented. Even intellisense returns the same documentation. The first seems to be more prevalent. Is there a reason to use one over the other?

Comment: `typeof(Type).GetTypeInfo()` return `TypeInfo` and `typeof(Type)` return `Type` and `TypeInfo` inherit from `Type` and implement `IReflectableType`. so both `Assembly` are the same thing.

Comment: It seems strange that the former seems more prevalent than the later though. Especially since `typeof(Type).Assembly` is more concise.

Comment: @AndyCox: I think "more prevalent" *very* much depends on the date on which the code was written - see my answer for reasons :)

Comment: TypeInfo was an unfortunate hack in .NET 4.5 to make reflection available in WinRT.  If you write a UWP app then you can only use TypeInfo, not Type.  It has something to do with WinRT types not being .NET types at all, the language projection built into the CLR makes them look like they are.  They couldn't make Type work as-is, TypeInfo was the result.

Answer (score 8):

They both do the same thing. IIRC, `Type.GetTypeInfo()` returns `this` in (almost?) all cases.

The reason you'll see references to `type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly` is that the `Type.Assembly` property wasn't present in .NET Core 1.x, along with a lot of other reflection members. So if you had old .NET Framework code using reflection, you had to sprinkle `.GetTypeInfo()` all over the place to get it to work with .NET Core 1.x.

The same code continues to work for more modern versions of .NET Core and .NET, but I suspect that many people (such as myself) haven't been bothered to go round and remove all the now-redundant `GetTypeInfo()` calls.

Answer (score 2):

I was just wondering the exact same thing.

Seems like it's possible that `TypeInfo` could be more lightweight to use than `Type`.

Below snippet was grabbed from [this article](https://dailydotnettips.com/type-and-typeinfo-the-two-new-faces-of-object-metadata/)

[image: type vs typeinfo - dailydotnettips]

Edit:

As Jon rightly points out this **won't** be more lightweight for the Assembly property. It seems I was not wondering the exact same thing, instead I was trying to understand the difference between `Type` and `TypeInfo` which is explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo?view=net-6.0#remarks).

Comment: It won't be any more lightweight for the `Assembly` property. What the article is getting at is that `Type` has members such as `Type.GetMethods()` that return arrays - a new array *has* to be allocated on each call (unless it's empty) because arrays are always mutable. Compare that with the members of `TypeInfo` such as `TypeInfo.DeclaredMethods` which return `IEnumerable<MethodInfo>` - that can be lazy and cached.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes that is quite correct - I could delete my answer, I got sidetracked with my own question and did not answer the OP's more specific question...